# What to do about new users posting useless answers only to make themselves known?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, old-questions, new-users

I've recently often witnessed the quite sad phenomenon of new (and often clueless) users trying to make themselves known by adding useless answers to already-answered questions, or [to old unanswered (and often unanswerable) questions](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9691/old-and-useless-questions-bumped-to-home-page-by-community).

This is becominig increasingly common, and increasingly disturbing; the most disturbing effect is the fact that any question that receives a new answer gets bumped to home page, cluttering it even more than it already is.

How can this problem be mitigated?

Comment: It's not a great sign of community health that we don't have enough incoming new questions to provide new-comers a chance to get heard.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 I totally agree. But newcomers posting useless answers to old and meaningless questions is actually a problem. I'd totally like to give them better chances to be useful. But this is really something they should *not* do.

Comment: This feels like something our users with enough reputation could help with. Start _protecting_ seriously out of date questions. Since that's most of the database at this point, that's a lot of work. Anything structural would have to happen at the Staff level.

Comment: Can you show a specific example of such a 'useless' answer in context? Right now your question would be considered not answerable because not enough information is provided to answer if it were on the regular site.

Answer (score 2):

You have all the tools you need to deal with this on a case by case basis yourself.

If an answer is useless then simply downvote it.

You could also consider protecting the question to stop it from being used in a similar manner in the future.

Beyond that, there is likely little that can be done.